# How to add a theme in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: error]
I want to add expressiondark theme on WPF.

in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="ThemesSample.App" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    StartupUri="MYWINDOW.xaml"> 
    <Application.Resources> 
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ExpressionDark.xaml"/> 
    </Application.Resources> 
</Application>
```

in MainWindow.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{ 
    ResourceDictionary skin = new ResourceDictionary(); 
    skin.Source = new Uri(@"MYPROJECTADDR\ExpressionDark.xaml", UriKind.Absolute); 
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(skin); 
}
```

and added expressiondark.xaml in project. But there are errors all xmlns lines in xpressiondark.xaml.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you add the ExpressionDark.xaml to the project?

Comment: Please show us the errors you get...

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/hata1uy.jpg/

Comment: For some weird reason I can't see the picture in imageshack. Can you add a screenshot to the original question?

Comment: ok.I added.do you think what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the ScreenShot of your ExpressionDark.xaml the ResourceDictionary section contains alot of xmlns tags that my version of ExpressionDark.xaml does not have, my version only includes:

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
```

Where did you get your `ExpressionDark.xaml` file?

Try with this one:
 http://wpf.codeplex.com/downloads/get/62512

Comment: thanks I get it and gived to correct expressiondark.xaml adress in public MainWindow(){}.the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

You can try using NuGet to install theme. 
From VS, go to Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Cnsole
and write the following command to install theme
PM> Install-Package WPF.Themes 
this will make a directory in your project called Themes and download all the themes. it will also add ResourceDirectory to yourApp.xaml where you can select the desired theme.
Now you just need to drag and drop the tools when you run your app you will see the theme.